# Accidently Deactivate the Cloudflare plugin in wordpress now site not loading

Tags: wordpress

I was deactivating the unused plugin but i had configured cloudflare and cloudflare-flexible-ssl unfortunately accidently the plugin get deactivate. Now i open the site to activate them its shows 
This page isn’t working www.my1004mart.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

How could i fix and reactivate those plugin.

[image]

Comment: no its not the issue

Comment: This error fixed the issue was i disable flexible SSL plugin, the website url was configure with https:// so thats way it was stuck in redirect loop.